# Kibana displaying JSON incorrectly

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm using ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) for logging purposes. The problem is Kibana doesn't seem to recognize my JSON, because it puts my JSON inside `message`.

Here's how I run Logstash:

> bin/logstash -e 'input { udp { port => 5000 type => json_logger } }
>   output { stdout { } elasticsearch { host => localhost } }'

Here's an example Logstash output for my logs (for debugging purposes I also output logs to stdout):

> 2014-10-07T10:28:19.104+0000 127.0.0.1
>   {"user_id":1,"object_id":6,"@timestamp":"2014-10-07T13:28:19.101+03:00","@version":"1","severity":"INFO","host":"sergey-System"}

How do I make Elasticsearch/Kibana/Logstash recognize JSON?

Comment: Try `bin/logstash -e 'input { udp { port => 5000 type => json_logger codec => json} } output { stdout { } elasticsearch { host => localhost } }'`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiStefan !
It worked. Would you mind adding this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `bin/logstash -e 'input { udp { port => 5000 type => json_logger codec => json} } output { stdout { } elasticsearch { host => localhost } }'`.

Note the `codec => json` option.